# How to check target.com for product availability using python requests and pandas modules

Tags: python, pandas, stock

Using something similar to the below, is there a way I can tell if a specific product is in stock in the surrounding stores?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.get('https://www.target.com')

key = s.cookies['visitorId']
location = s.cookies['GuestLocation'].split('|')[0]

store_id = requests.get('https://redsky.target.com/v3/stores/nearby/%s?key=%s&limit=1&within=100&unit=mile' %(location, key)).json()
store_id = store_id[0]['locations'][0]['location_id']

product_id = '52190942'
url = 'https://redsky.target.com/web/pdp_location/v1/tcin/%s' %product_id
payload = {'pricing_store_id': store_id,'key': key}


jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['price'], index=[0])
```

Comment: If it's returning a list of stores, just loop through them checking the availability.

Comment: but I don't think there is a tag to check for availability is the issue. I hoping someone knows of another key:value pair I can add to the 'payload' to return the stock availability